Hooking WASM Functions On Web Page
Is there a way to hook a function inside a WebAssembly running on a web page? Usually Frida works for standalone application, but I have no idea how to do it on WebAssembly.

wasm has a sandbox and so does the browser. You can only inject hooks if your application launches and/or embeds the browser.

If I try to put it in Android WebView will it be able to bee hooked? @browsermator

yes, see here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript
